# Is it possible to exclude all the bugs reported by findbugs using Regex?

Tags: java, maven, findbugs

I am completely new to Maven. I am trying to exclude all the bugs reported by the findbugs plugin from all the classes in a project by a regex in findbugs filter file which matches everything such as ~.* as shown in the below code, but it isn't working. Is this possible at first place? if so how? Thanks in advance!

```
<FindBugsFilter>
    <Class name="~.*"/>
    <Bug pattern="~.*"/>
</FindBugsFilter>
```

Added Reference of exclusion file in pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <findbugs.includeTests>findbugsfilter.xml</findbugs.includeTests>
    <checkstyle.suppressions.location>suppression.xml</checkstyle.suppressions.location>
</properties>
```

Comment: You need to configure the findbugs plugin in pom.xml see https://gleclaire.github.io/findbugs-maven-plugin/usage.html the find bugs filter is a separate file.

Comment: Yea already did that! Edited the question now.